# How can I get intersection points of two adjustable curves dynamically?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, manipulate

[image]I need to show the intersection points of any two lines and dynamically adjust the lines to get new intersection points, what is the easiest way?

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{(n - x) m, x*l, x (n - x) m - (x - 1)*(n - x + 1) m}, {x, 1, 
   If[n <= 10, 10, n]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic], {{n, 10}, 0, 100, 
  0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{m, 1}, 0, 100, 0.1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{l, 1}, 0, 100, 0.1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[x1, x2, l, m, n]
x1[l_, n_, m_] := x /. First@Solve[(n - x) m == x*l, x]
x2[l_, n_, m_] := x /. First@Solve[x (n - x) m - (x - 1)*(n - x + 1) m == x l, x]


Manipulate[Plot[{(n - x) m, x*l, x (n - x) m - (x - 1)*(n - x + 1) m}, {x, 1, 
   If[n <= 10, 10, n]}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{#, l #} & /@ {x1[l, n, m], x2[l, n, m]}]}], 
  {{n, 10}, 0, 100, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{m, 1}, 0, 100, 0.1,  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{l, 1}, 0, 100, 0.1,  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]